# SSD IOPS inquire

Tags: ssd, iops, nvme

I have question about IOPS

For example is there difference in IOPS if the SSD was ( sata 2.5 or M.2 sata or M.2 M-key nvme )

i know

sata interface = 600MB

M.2 sata = 600MB

m.2 M-Key nvme = 2000MB

But I am asking about IOPS of them same or there is big differences ?

In fact I have searched in Google but didn't find the right answer for me or maybe i have some confusing, I know some times there are some differences between some ssds depend on  the price and company and some other things

So in Google say IOPS of SSD from  4500 - 100k depends on type

So I hope get clear answer on my question

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the maximum U.2/M.2 NVMe throughput with PCIe 4.0x4 is 7.8 GB/s.

SATA 6G limits the I/O performance to ~145,000 IOPS, SAS 12G is roughly twice that. U.2/M.2 NVMe (PCIe 4.0) approaches 1,000,000 IOPS.

Of course, everything depends on the actual hardware at hand, SSD and host.